# I couldn't compile this little query (needs 2 tables)(mysql)

Tags: mysql, join

i have 2 tables as like seen :

user table  :   id, userid , country

friends table :  id, userid , friendid

so i want to get friendid rows from friends table where friends.userid == user.userid  and user.country='USA' ?

thanks for your helps

Comment: What exact error you are getting?

Comment: there is no error i say i couldnt compile the right query : ) and friendids should be unique ?

Comment: This is too basic for dba.se - try SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select f.friendid from friends f, user u where u.userid = f.userid and u.country = 'usa';
```

if you are using any query and it throws an error please describe your error...

Comment: Do not teach people to use SQl antipatterns like implicit joins.

Answer (score 3):

```
select f.friendid 
from friends f  
  inner join user u 
    on u.userid = f.userid 
where u.country='usa'
```